# php DOMDocument: how can I print an attribute of an element?

Tags: php, dom, xpath, xpathquery

How do I print the an attribute of an element?

example:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTML($page);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$arts= $xpath->query("/td");

foreach ($arts as $art) {
   // here i wanna print the attribute class of the td element, how do i do so ?
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [DOMElement::getAttribute](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php)

```
$art->getAttribute('class');
```

also, [simpleHTMLDOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) is more suitable for dealing with html:

```
$html = str_get_html($page);
foreach($html->find('td') as $element) 
   echo $element->class.'<br>';
}
```

Comment: Care to elaborate why SimpleHtmlDom is "more suitable" than DOM for dealing with HTML? DOM handles HTML fine.

Answer (score 1):

[`DOMXPath`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)'s [`query`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php) function returns a [`DOMNodeList`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php), <s>which (I'm pretty sure) cannot be used in a `foreach($ARRAY)` loop</s> **[Edit: it can]**. <s>You'll have to implement a modified `for` loop in order to read the [`DOMNode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php) elements inside the list class:</s> **[Edit: not necessary; see below]**

```
foreach ($arts as $art) {
     # code-hardiness checking
     if ($art && $art->hasAttributes()) {
         # (note: chaining will only work in PHP 5+)
         $class = $art->attributes->getNamedItem('class');
         print($class . "\n");
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info. just so you'll know, it does support foreach :)

Comment: `Class [ <internal:dom> <iterateable> class DOMNodeList ]` which means it can be used in a `foreach` construct

Comment: <td> is a DOMElement (not just a DOMNode), so $art->getAttribute('class') would suffice.